# Member 'success' in 'SingleEvent<_>' produces result of type 'SingleEvent<Element>'

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

can someone explain what is the error here ?

```
Member 'success' in 'SingleEvent<_>' produces result of type 'SingleEvent<Element>', but context expects 'SingleEvent<_>'
```

I return a Single either error or success with a generic type
if the result case is .success I want to pass JSON in the single event

[image]

this is the full code

```
import Foundation
import RxSwift

public class APIClient<T: APIProtocol> {
    var disposeBag: DisposeBag = DisposeBag()
}

extension APIClient {
    public func get<U>(apiService: T, key: String) -> Single<U> {
        return Single.create { single in

            let task = TaskRequestManager.run(apiService, completion: { result in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    switch result {

                    case .error(let error):
                        single(.error(error))
                    case .success(let json):

                        guard let JSON = json[key] as? [String: Any] else {
                            single(.error(ApiError.jsonParsingFailure))
                            return
                        }
                        single(.success(JSON))
                    }
                }

            })
            task.resume()
            return Disposables.create {
                task.cancel()
            }
    }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Return type of `get` function is `Single<U>`, while calling of `single(.success(JSON))` violates this by specifying concrete type `Single<[String: Any]>`. Either replace generic type `U` with `Dictionary<String, Any>` in `get` function, either make  `TaskRequestManager.run` accept generic type.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
return Single.create { single in
```

into this

```
return Single<U>.create { single in
```